# How to solve this using regex?

Tags: python, regex

Given that string:

```
\n
\n
text1\n
\ttext2\n
  Message: 1st message\n
some more text\n
\n
\n
  Message: 2dn message\n\n
\t\t
Message: 3rd message\n
text3\n
```

I want to extract messages from a multiline string (token is 'Message: '). What regex expression should I use to capture those 3 groups:

- group 1 : '1st message'
- group 2 : '2dn message'
- group 3 : '3rd message'

I tried a lot of things but I can get the expression to work because the string is a multiline string.

*My program is in python 2.6 but I suppose it does not make a big difference what language I use...*

Comment: you don't care for `some more text` and `text` parts that are on the next lines? post your regex

Comment: correct; I just want the content on the same line as 'Message:'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> re.findall('Message: (.+?)$', s, re.M)
['1st message', '2dn message', '3rd message']
```

[`re.M` flag gives special meaning to `^` and `$`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.M):

> When specified, the pattern character `'^'` matches at the beginning of the string and at the beginning of each line (immediately following each newline); and the pattern character `'$'`  matches at the end of the string and at the end of each line (immediately preceding each newline). By default, `'^'` matches only at the beginning of the string, and `'$'` only at the end of the string and immediately before the newline (if any) at the end of the string.

`(.+?)$` matches at least one character till the closest end of the string-character.

**edit**: indeed the simple version will work too:

```
>>> re.findall('Message: (.+)', s)
['1st message', '2dn message', '3rd message']
```

I'm surprised it wasn't in the list of those numerous things you tried :)

Comment: If that's what he wants, why not just re.findall('Message: (.+)', s)?

Comment: I'm totally new to regex and I was on the wrong track. First I was trying to use `match`, not `findall` (I'm not to sure what each one does but I'll read on that). And for some reason, I thought I had to use wildcards at the beginning of the expression.

Comment: @Sly: `findall` is similar to `search` rather than `match`, except it doesn't stop after finding a match but continues and try to match more stuff and accumulates everything in the list. `match` starts searching from the beginning of the string only. And no, you don't have to use use wildcards at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 0):

@OP,you don't need a regex. Assuming you don't care about the lines after `"Message:"`,

```
for line in mystring.split("\n")
    if "Message:" in line:
         print "found: ",line
```